# Python Matplotlib doesn't show figure facecolor when saving figure / plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization

I'm currently having an issue with saving colors and matplotlib. When I run the following code I get the expected result

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.title("test")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:mint green')

plt.show()
```

Here is a screenshot of what is shown, which is the result I'm expecting.

[image: Correct output]

However, when I run the save function either through python or by manually clicking save on the figure it results in the following image, without the colored borders.

[image]

Code to reproduce image above

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.title("test")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:mint green')

# Also doesn't work with fig.savefig
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=200)
```

Comment: `savefig` has an explicit argument to set the facecolor. It should be set again. The reasoning probably is that when saving an image to be part of a document meant to be printed, having a white background is often preferred. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohanC pointed out in the comments it takes a face color arguement.

Fixed code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.title("test")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')

# Also doesn't work with fig.savefig
plt.savefig("test.png", facecolor='xkcd:mint green', dpi=200)
```